# SourceTreeの樹形図について

Tags: git

[SourceTree](https://www.atlassian.com/ja/software/sourcetree/overview)の樹形図の見方がいまいち分からず、皆様のお力を借りたく投稿しました。

仕事で今度からSourceTreeを使っていくという事で、色々といじくっていたのですが、樹形図の一番左にあるブランチは何を示しているのでしょうか？
現在チェックアウトしているブランチかと思ってましたが、切り替えても別にブランチの列は変わらず…。最新コミットを持つブランチかな？とも思ったのですが、ある方のブログでは「一番コミット数が多いブランチ」などとも書いてあり、混乱しております。

直接作業には関わらない事ではありますが、今後SourceTreeを十分に活用してきたいので、どなたかご存知の方はご教授のほど、よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 3):

"default branch"と設定したものが一番左 (leftmost one)になるのではないでしょうか。

このあたりで議論されています (詳細は読み切れてません) 
[Atlassian Answers](http://answers.atlassian.com/questions/310287)

> Any other branch can be configured to be the default branch. Saying this, it does not make sense to have master branch displayed always leftmost.

(訳: どのブランチでもdefault branchにできます。 つまり、一番左が常にmasterブランチとは限らないよ)

default branchの設定方法は以下に投稿しました。
[default branchの設定方法](http://qiita.com/7of9/items/d6b0fea5c3a171553e12)